# How to store file to gcp cloud storage from browser javascript without OAuth authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload file to GCP cloud storage from browser but it support OAuth authentication.

Is there any way to store file without using OAuth and can only be use api key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "signed URL" mechanism.
By using it, you can temporarily allow anyone who knows the URL to upload files to your cloud storage.

1. generate a special temporary URL (signed URL) in your backend
2. return that URL to the browser
3. upload a file to that URL by the javascript in the browser

references

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-nodejs